# How do you access all the items within a folder directory?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to make a small website in vanilla JS and I am almost done. I think it would be a great way to save time if I was able to update directories by adding files to them and having JS dynamically throw the stuff onto the website. Bad design, I know, but my website looks like a terminal so I'm hoping it will look fine.

So in Python it would look like this:

```
import os
os.listdir("somedirectory")
```

And it would print the items within the directory I've specified. But how do you do this same thing in JS? The only options I've seen use JQuery or Node.js, is there any "plain jane" way to accomplish this?

[So, if I went to the Safety-Net directory I would see 'cover.jpg'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU2F6.png)

An important piece of info is to state that these folders would be clientside, and the user would be able to see all the files within it.

Edit: I do NOT want to write files, just to read them.

https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/using-file-and-folder-objects.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The current code will give a list of all files in a folder, assuming it's on the server side you want to list all files:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('/assets/photos/');
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot access files if not using server side JS, but the XMLHttpRequest object can be used to read files. You can send AJAX request to read file but some where on server side you have to use Nodejs or other server side JS lib to access file system

Using nodejs you can use following methods to access directory

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

These are few options to access all data in the directory in NodeJS